# Can not get value spinner from listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

Sorry for my english. I spent meny times try fix my problem, but I could not do it. I have listView, in this list view for some elements create spinner. Spinner created in adapter. I cant get value spinner. Its vary hard from me. Please healp

My adapter

```
   public class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mGroups;
        private ArrayList<DeviceObject> deviceObList;
        private ArrayList<RoomSuggestion> roObjList;
        private Context mContext;

        public ExpListAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groups, ArrayList<DeviceObject> deviceObList, ArrayList<RoomSuggestion> roObjList){
            mContext = context;
            mGroups = groups;
            this.deviceObList = deviceObList;
            this.roObjList = roObjList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return mGroups.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return mGroups.get(groupPosition).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return mGroups.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                                 ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);
            }

            if (isExpanded){
                //Изменяем что-нибудь, если текущая Group раскрыта
            }
            else{
                //Изменяем что-нибудь, если текущая Group скрыта
            }

            Typeface lightFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "font/GothamProLight.ttf");

            TextView textGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGroup);

            textGroup.setTypeface(lightFace);
            textGroup.setText("Thereses gate 46");

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
            }

            Typeface mediumFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "font/GothamProMedium.ttf");

            TextView textChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textChild);
            textChild.setTypeface(mediumFace);
            textChild.setText( mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition) );

            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bg_button_screen);

            if( !deviceObList.get(childPosition).getProduct_id().equals("0") ) {
                rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4fcc54"));

View linearLayoutG =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 30);
                linearLayoutG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                RelativeLayout spinnerOpen = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerOpen);
                View linearLayout =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);

                ImageView imageS = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerImage);
                imageS.getLayoutParams().width = 20;
                imageS.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
                imageS.setImageResource(R.drawable.spin_ok);

                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i = 0; i < roObjList.size(); i++) {
                    list.add(roObjList.get(i).getName() );
                }

                final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(mContext);
                //Make sure you have valid layout parameters.
                spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));

                spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_spinner);

                ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext,
                        R.layout.spinner_item, list);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                //open spinner
                spinnerOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        spinner.performClick();
                    }
                });

                ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(spinner);

                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Log.e("selected", String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position)) );
                        Log.e("childPosition", String.valueOf(childPosition));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            } else {
                rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e5910d"));
            }





        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My xml from adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bgchilddevice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#26ffffff"
            android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textChild"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bg_button_screen"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#4fcc54"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/check"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#26ffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/spinnerL"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/spinnerOpen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerImage"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And that i try get spinner elements

```
create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        for(int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++ ) {

                    for(int j = 0; j < listView.getChildCount(); j++ ) {

                        View _mainView = listView.getChildAt(j);

                        LinearLayout _linearLayout = (LinearLayout) _mainView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);

                        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) _linearLayout.getChildAt(0);

                        String selection = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();

                        Log.e("spinner device", selection);
                    }

                }
    }

});
```

And **i have**

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException`

in line `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) _linearLayout.getChildAt(0);`

**i try write**

`Spinner spinner = (Spinner) _linearLayout.getChildAt(0);`

`Spinner spinner = (Spinner) _linearLayout.getChildAt(1);`

`Spinner spinner = (Spinner) _linearLayout.getChildAt(2);`

`Spinner spinner = (Spinner) _linearLayout.getChildAt(3);`

its error

Comment: So it sounds like you have different views depending on the position in list. Some have a spinner and some dont. Correct?

Comment: @doubleA yes it is. One element can equals or not spinner

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `findViewById()` for the spinner?

```
Spinner spinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);
String value = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: thanks for answer, because I create spinner in adapter like this `final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(mContext);` and then i add spinner to LinearLayout like this `((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(spinner)`

Comment: Is there a reason you are adding your spinner in code and do not have it in a layout resource file?

Comment: @doubleA somthing element from listView dont equals spinner

Answer (score 0):

I dont know it bad code or not, i try write like this and its work!!!

```
for(int j = 0; j < listView.getChildCount(); j++ ) {

                        View _mainView = listView.getChildAt(j);

                        LinearLayout _linearLayout = (LinearLayout) _mainView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);

                        try{
                            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) _linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
                            String selection = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();

                            Log.e("spinner device", selection);


                        }catch(Exception e){

                        }
                    }
```